# How to handle rejection with Multiple RCPT TO?

Tags: smtp

I run a mail service.

Some servers send me emails with multiple `RCPT TO` (max@test.com, andrew@test.com, bob@test.com, etc.).

The issue is that it might happens that bob@test.com inbox is full, so his email will be rejected.

Unfortunately, this happens on the `DATA` command, and if I return a `4xx` error here, this will be for all the RCPT TO (afaik).

Worse, while looping on the TOs, I can deliver emails for the first and second email, and fail on the third (quota, or any other error). In that case, I will return a `5xx` to the sending domain **even though** the first two emails were successfully delivered.

How can I do in that case? Is there a specific response in SMTP that says *"email X and Y were good, but not Z"*?

Answer (score 0):

You could issue the sender a delivery status notification message with a "failed to deliver" error.

But yea, there's no error code that you could return in response to the `DATA` command that clients could use to know that bob failed but the others succeeded.

You have to issue those errors in response to the `RCPT TO` command if you are going to provide that type of error.